# What is the decoherence time scale for the most promising quantum computing implementations

Tags: quantum-information, resource-recommendations, quantum-computer, decoherence, coherence

I'm searching for some data about decoherence time scales for qubits in modern quantum computing implementations.

The only reference I have is a table in "Quantum computation and quantum information" - Nielsen&Chuang , but it's an "old" book and with no references for the values.

(references are very appreciated)

edit: with data I mean time scales

Answer (score 0):

Different physical system has their own decoherence time of qubit.A large decoherence time scale  means you have enough time to perform quantum information proccessing (inchude quantum computing) .The time for the same operation in different physical system are different and even they are not in an order of magnitude. So,the decoherence time scale is for different physical systems.

Comment: Long coherence time is only meaningful relative to the gate times.

Comment: My bad, I should have been more clear. I'm searching for some up to date table/article/whatever with real coherence times - gate times.